# Materialized view in postgres from the variables rather than SQL query results

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, materialized-views, user-variables

I have a stored procedure in Postgres. I have generated some variables in that procedure. These variables are generated inside a loop of query result. Suppose if i have 10 rows from my query then for 10 times I am generating those variables.

Now I want to create a materialized view where these variables will be the columns and every row will have values of those variables generated in every iteration of that loop.

What can be the better approach for this?

I can create a temporary table with those variables and insert values in every iteration of that loop but that will not serve my purpose. Because I want to drop my existing table where all the values are available and columns are those variables. My target is to make a materialized view with those variables so that I can get rid of that parent table.

For more detail, I have a table. suppose it has 5 columns. all the column values can be calculated implementing equation. So now I want to drop this table. Rather I want to implement materialize view for that and I have written a stored procedure for generating column values. Now the problem is materialize usually works with the query result which comes from other table columns but in my case i have variables which are generated in that stored procedure.

This is the sample main block of my stored procedure:

```
FOR inst_id IN SELECT h_inst.id from mytable h_inst loop
    
    SELECT f_get_value_year(inst_id, 2014) into t_14;
    SELECT f_get_value_year(inst_id, 2015) into t_15;

    select find_max_float(b) into max_t;
    t_14_n := t_14 / max_t;
    t_15_n := t_15 / max_t;
END LOOP;
```

So here t_14_n and t_15_n are generated in every iteration of the loop. So i want all the values under t_14_n and t_15_n column and then return it to my materialized view.

Comment: I don't understand why a table of the results won't serve your purpose. There isn't enough information - perhaps you could provide a small example?

Comment: I have a table. suppose it has 5 columns. all the column values can be calculated implementing equation. So now I want to drop this table. Rather I want to implement materialize view for that and  I have written a stored procedure for generating column values. 
Now the problem is materialize usually works with the query result which comes from other table columns but in my case i have variables which are generated in that stored procedure.

Comment: Please post sample data, the calculations, and the expected output of your procedure. All as text - **no images**.

Comment: @Belayer. I have added example in the post.